# Can data augmentation cause slower learning for CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on an image pixel classification problem and use
data augmentation (in Keras).

So I apply data transformations (rotations, flips) to image patches. My code for data augmentation and training the CNN is given below.

```python
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
       horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
)

batch_size=16
epochs=50

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=Adam(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])


model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('myweights.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

callbacks_list = [plot_losses,model_checkpoint]

history=model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,
                    validation_data = datagen.flow(x_valid, y_valid, batch_size=batch_size),
                    validation_steps=x_valid.shape[0] // batch_size,
                    epochs = epochs, verbose = 1)
```

My train/validation accuracy and loss plots are as follows:
[image]

I can see there is a general continual increase in accuracy and drop in loss , which is what we want. But it is very slow across 20 epochs. Without data augmentation my accuracy increases faster.

So why is it that data augmentation results in such a slow learning process (approximately 48% to 58% training/valid accuracy increase over 20 epochs)?

I am using the `Adam optimizer` which uses exponential learning rate decay, so I do not believe a new learning rate schedule would affect much unless I am missing something. Any insights are welcome.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You mean slow as in "it takes more epochs", or as in "each epoch is taking longer"? If it is the first, where is the comparison with the not-augmented data? What exactly is the "approximately 50% to 58% training/valid accuracy increase over 20 epochs" you report (your accuracy y-axis goes from 0.48 to 0.58)??

Comment: by slow I mean it there is only an approximate  10% increase in accuracy over 20 epochs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is expected behavior when use data augmentation for your model to train slower. Augmentation flips, rotates and in general transforms an image to enlarge our data set. This is done with CPU which is slower than GPU.

We use augmentation not for speed but for increased accuracy.

Comment: Correct answer (+1), only if by slow OP means "each epoch is taking longer" (see comment in OP), but I am not sure this is the case... @unknown121 yes, `datagen.flow` is being done on the CPU